# List to CSV and Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `List<Customer>` which holds **5,000 lines** where `Customer` is

```
public class Customer{

    public Int32 CustomerID {get;set;}

    public String Name {get;set;}

    public Decimal AccountPrice {get;set;}


}
```

I want to convert this List to a **CSV** and offer it as a download to the browser.  I have the code which successfully returns the stream `HttpContextBase` but the contents of the file is not working.

I have tried

```
String.Join("," customers.Select(x=> new{ Name = x.Name.ToString(), AccountPrice = AccountPrice.ToString() }).ToArray());
```

but this is not working with exception anonymous type `ToArray()` Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to do everything in 1 line. As a rookie, you'll never be able to learn or debug anything this way.

Comment: As @banging said. What is about a simple `foreach` loop? I guess this would be good enough.

Comment: If you have a lot of "clever code" in what you write, please be sure to document it with comments.  Even if you're maintaining your own code, it can be easy to forget your mindset at the time you wrote it and why you did it the way you did.  Imagine what it will be like for someone else maintaining it?

Comment: What if the Customer Name has comma in it? That's going to mess up your CSV file. What you are trying to do, and the other solutions provided by the other people here, do not take that into account. You should not only separate the values with comma, but also put them into quotation marks. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you insist on one line...

```
List<Customer> myList;

String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,myList.Select(c=>String.Join(",", new[]{c.ID.ToString(), c.Name}));
```

Or you can do it with an iteration. **Compacted code should be preferred... except when it's harder to read**

Here's a compact but still readable version:

```
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

myList.ForEach(c=>{
   csv.Append(c.ID).Append(",");
   csv.Append(c.Name).Append(System.Environment.NewLine); 
});
```

Comment: Nice comment: you should always choose the simplest code to read. +1 :)

Comment: How does that help when OP want to exprot to Excel (.xls / .xlsx) ?

Comment: @ablaze: Read the question again, he wants to offer the file to be downloaded, nothing about Excel there.

Comment: I see it in bold faced fonts, in subject : "List to CSV and Excel" ... csv AND EXCEL.

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("Name");
sb.Append(",");
sb.Append("Account Price");
sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);

foreach (Customer c in customers)
{
    sb.Append(c.Name);
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(c.AccountPrice);
    sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
}

 string csv = sb.ToString();
```

This is much easier for me to read at a glance.  In your attempt you don't use a new line, which is necessary for creating rows in a CSV, just so you know.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I usually do it. I have a CSVResult class that extends the FileResult class like following:

```
public class CSVResult : FileResult
{
    private IQueryable _data;
    private string[] _headers;

    public CSVResult(string fileName, IQueryable data)
        : base("text/csv")
    {
        this.FileDownloadName = fileName;
        _data = data;
    }

    public CSVResult(string fileName, IQueryable data, string[] headers)
        : this(fileName, data)
    {
        _headers = headers;
    }

    // Returns a string array containing the headers (column names) 
    private string[] GetHeaders()
    {
        var headers = (from p in _data.ElementType.GetProperties()
                        select p.Name).ToArray();

        return headers;
    }

    // Writes the CSV file to the http response 
    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteObject(memoryStream);
            outputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }

    // Writes the CSV data into a stream
    private void WriteObject(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        if (_headers == null)
        {
            _headers = GetHeaders();
        }

        // First line for column names                        
        foreach (var h in _headers)
        {
            writer.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\",", h));
        }

        writer.WriteLine();

        foreach (var row in _data)
        {
            foreach (var p in row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var value = p.GetValue(row, null);
                string strValue = value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();

                writer.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\",", strValue));
            }

            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in your Controller like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToCSV() 
{
    var data = customers.AsQueryable();
    var fileName = "customers.csv";

    return new CSVResult(fileName, data);
}
```

When you don't provide column names, the CSVResult class uses the property names as column names. But, you can also provide column names like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToCSV() 
{
    var data = customers.AsQueryable();
    var fileName = "customers.csv";
    string[] headers = new string[] { "Customer ID", "Customer Name", "Account Price" };

    return new CSVResult(fileName, data, headers);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use OLEDB, as for an example you can do somoething like follwing for CSV and quite similar for Excel

```
//Target Database: CSV
string strBasePath = @"C:\Database";
string strFilename = @"NewCSV.csv";
string CSVConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" + strBasePath + @"';Extended Properties='text; HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';";
```

and then :

```
using (OleDbConnection CSVConnection = new OleDbConnection(CSVConnectionString))
{
     try
     {
         CSVConnection.Open();
         string strInsertCommand = @"INSERT INTO " + strFilename + @" (CustomerID, CustomerName, Country) VALUES (@custid, @name, @country)";
         OleDbCommand InsertCommanmd = CSVConnection.CreateCommand();
         InsertCommanmd.CommandText = strInsertCommand;

         foreach ( var item in List<T> )
         {
             InsertCommanmd.Parameters.Clear();
             InsertCommanmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custid", item.prop1);
             InsertCommanmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", item.prop2);
             InsertCommanmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", item.prop3);
             InsertCommanmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
     finally
     {
          if (!CSVConnection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
              CSVConnection.Close();
     }
}
```

For getting headstart in Excel :

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Path\Book81.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
ExcelConnection.Open();
string update = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Name='Smith Jones' where name='Smith'";
OleDbCommand UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(update, ExcelConnection);
UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: -1 ohmy, this is the most overbloated piece of code - not only it's long but it introduces dependencies on COM components - a nightmare in its own right. This is what crashy slow and unportable apps are made of.

Comment: Certainly you're right, for csv, one may use yours but for Excel,  do you think that you're solution is helping ? 
No other solution including yours ( so far ) has shown up that says how to covnert to Excel, which seemes to be also a part of the actual question.
If the intetion is just to downlaod a simple csv file, yours is a part of an elegent solution !

Comment: maybe you posted on the wrong question? your answer won't even work on a (shared) server or if you manage to make it work it won't be stable, see Microsoft's own recommendations on using Office API on a server.

Comment: maybe you posted on the wrong question? your answer won't even work on a (shared) server or if you manage to make it work it won't be stable   --> **I do not know what you're trying to convey ?** And for Microsoft's recommendations I think you could've shared [some link](http://officewebviewer.com) but you know it may not add meaning when OP wants to export a grid !

Comment: here's the link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757.  In the More Information section it says: Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services)

Comment: what I mean by "shared server" is one where you just get a folder for your site in IIS - you may not even have the security permissions to instantiate COM interop objects

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, I'll update my answer with Open SDK as soon as get a chance.